# Не выполняется цикл do

Tags: java, циклы

Не могу понять в чем дело. Цикл `do\while` с меткой `setSize` не выполняется ни разу, из за чего массив не инициализируется. Цикл `do` должен выполниться хотя бы один раз, верно?

```
int bound;
int array[];
setSize: do {
    System.out.println("Введите желаемую длинну для нового массива");
    bound = getInt();
    if (bound <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Длинна массива не может быть отрицательной или нулевой!");
        continue setSize;
    }
    array = new int[bound];
} while (bound <= 0);

System.out.println("Создан массив array длинной " + array.length + " элементов!");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Введите число для элемента массива с индексом: " + i);
    array[i] = getInt();
}
```

Comment: А оно точно компилируется? Там как минимум нужно писать вместо `int array[];` следующее `int array[] = {};` либо менять логику.

Comment: а что за интересная конструкция  setSize: do {} - это компилируется?

Comment: @KirillStoianov я так понимаю, это метка

Comment: continue с меткой. компилируется.

Comment: а отлаживать пробовали по шагам?

Comment: Отлаживать пробовал, благодаря чему и обнаружил, что именно этот цикл просто игнорируется. Это учебное задание, и в программе есть еще два аналогичных цикла с меткой, которые нормально работают.

Comment: @SvyatoslavKaryuk 1) Решите проблему компиляции, как вам и указали. 2) Я так понимаю, что в таком контексте данная метка лишена смысла, т.е. программа сохранит свое поведение, если вы удалите метку и напишите просто `continue;` вместо `continue setSize;` (вот если бы у вас были вложенные циклы, например, и вам бы требовалось из внутреннего прыгнуть на следующую итерацию внешнего, тогда да)

Comment: что значит игнорируется? доходит до строки do и перепрыгивает весь цикл? или как?

Comment: это самый первый код в методе main, и программа начинает работать со строки "System.out.println("Создан массив array длинной " + array.length + " элементов!");" после него. Заметил, если закомментировать "if (bound <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Длинна массива не может быть отрицательной или нулевой!");
        continue setSize;
    }" все работает... только не выполняется проверка <=0

Comment: прозреваю, что компиляция все-таки не идет (и javac и ecj у меня не компилируют, т.к. не могут доказать, что `array` всегда будет инициализирован), и у вас запускается старая версия, в которой цикла нет. Если вы уверены в своей правоте, приведите код класса целиком, и укажите, как вы его компилируете и запускаете.

Comment: Не инициализирован массив  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The local variable array may not have been initialized
 The local variable array may not have been initialized
 The local variable array may not have been initialized

Comment: Массив не инициализирован, потому что цикл не выполняется ни разу

Comment: @SvyatoslavKaryuk Ваш код даже не скомпилируется потому, что компилятор не имеет уверенности в том, что в рантайме дойдет дело до инициализации до того (и вообще, что оно дойдет), как вы обратитесь к `array.length`, поэтому попробуйте, как вам и посоветовали, "пересобрать проект" (_Rebuild project_), а не просто запустить (_Run_), т.к. судя по всему у вас когда-то была выставлена галочка, которая отвечала за поведение при попытке выполнения кода, который не компилируется (и выставлена в состояние "запускать последнюю удачную конфигурацию проекта").